# How to obtain a list of available locale keys from momentjs with locale?

Tags: momentjs

I'd like to obtain the list of available locale keys. I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 32):

```
af = Afrikaans
ar-dz = Arabic (Algeria)
ar-kw = Arabic (Kuwait)
ar-ly = Arabic (Libya)
ar-ma = Arabic (Morocco)
ar-sa = Arabic (Saudi Arabia)
ar-tn = Arabic (Tunisia)
ar = Arabic
az = Azerbaijani
be = Belarusian
bg = Bulgarian
bm = Bambara
bn = Bengali
bo = Tibetan
br = Breton
bs = Bosnian
ca = Catalan
cs = Czech
cv = Chuvash
cy = Welsh
da = Danish
de-at = German (Austria)
de-ch = German (Switzerland)
de = German
dv = Divehi
el = Greek
en-au = English (Australia)
en-ca = English (Canada)
en-gb = English (United Kingdom)
en-ie = English (Ireland)
en-nz = English (New Zealand)
eo = Esperanto
es-do = Spanish (Dominican Republic)
es-us = Spanish (United States)
es = Spanish
et = Estonian
eu = Basque
fa = Persian
fi = Finnish
fo = Faroese
fr-ca = French (Canada)
fr-ch = French (Switzerland)
fr = French
fy = Western Frisian
gd = Scottish Gaelic
gl = Galician
gom-latn = gom (Latin)
gu = Gujarati
he = Hebrew
hi = Hindi
hr = Croatian
hu = Hungarian
hy-am = Armenian (Armenia)
id = Indonesian
is = Icelandic
it = Italian
ja = Japanese
jv = Javanese
ka = Georgian
kk = Kazakh
km = Khmer
kn = Kannada
ko = Korean
ky = Kirghiz
lb = Luxembourgish
lo = Lao
lt = Lithuanian
lv = Latvian
me = me
mi = Maori
mk = Macedonian
ml = Malayalam
mr = Marathi
ms-my = Malay (Malaysia)
ms = Malay
mt = Maltese
my = Burmese
nb = Norwegian Bokmål
ne = Nepali
nl-be = Dutch (Belgium)
nl = Dutch
nn = Norwegian Nynorsk
pa-in = Punjabi (India)
pl = Polish
pt-br = Portuguese (Brazil)
pt = Portuguese
ro = Romanian
ru = Russian
sd = Sindhi
se = Northern Sami
si = Sinhala
sk = Slovak
sl = Slovenian
sq = Albanian
sr-cyrl = Serbian (Cyrillic)
sr = Serbian
ss = Swati
sv = Swedish
sw = Swahili
ta = Tamil
te = Telugu
tet = Tetum
th = Thai
tl-ph = Tagalog (Philippines)
tlh = Klingon
tr = Turkish
tzl = tzl
tzm-latn = tzm (Latin)
tzm = tzm
uk = Ukrainian
ur = Urdu
uz-latn = Uzbek (Latin)
uz = Uzbek
vi = Vietnamese
x-pseudo = x-pseudo
yo = Yoruba
zh-cn = Chinese (China)
zh-hk = Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China)
zh-tw = Chinese (Taiwan)
```

Comment: This list needs to be updated, for example the 'en' does not exist anymore.

Comment: Better to look at 'moment' folder in the 'node_modules' folder then you'll know it's up to date.

Comment: The question was about how to get a list programmatically.

Answer (score 16):

Following method returns list of locales that have been loaded

> ```
> moment.locales()
> ```

[Commit id](https://github.com/moment/moment/commit/c0519b5b825b840ababb29dd2c3e516d50fad99e)

[New feature link](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/2932)

[Document link](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/getting-locale/)

Comment: current locale is by `moment.locale()` @HiteshSahu

Answer (score 5):

A good way of viewing an up-to-date list of locales is to look inside the 'node_modules/moment/locale' folder. Then you'll see a js file for each locale and you can even see more details for that locale in the js file.

Answer (score 3):

I have updated this list with latest update.

Original Locale List : https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/locale

I have made a list below

```html
<select id="moment-locale">
  <option value="af">Afrikaans</option>
  <option value="ar-dz">Arabic (Algeria)</option>
  <option value="ar-kw">Arabic (Kuwait)</option>
  <option value="ar-ly">Arabic (Libya)</option>
  <option value="ar-ma">Arabic (Morocco)</option>
  <option value="ar-sa">Arabic (Saudi Arabia)</option>
  <option value="ar-tn">Arabic (Tunisia)</option>
  <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
  <option value="az">Azerbaijani</option>  
  <option value="be">Belarusian</option>
  <option value="bg">Bulgarian</option>
  <option value="bm">Bambara</option>
  <option value="bn-bd">Bengali (Bangladesh)</option>
  <option value="bn">Bengali</option>
  <option value="bo">Tibetan</option>
  <option value="br">Breton</option>
  <option value="bs">Bosnian</option>    
  <option value="ca">Catalan</option>
  <option value="cs">Czech</option>
  <option value="cv">Chuvash</option>
  <option value="cy">Welsh</option>   
  <option value="da">Danish</option>
  <option value="de-at">German (Austria)</option>  
  <option value="de-ch">German (Switzerland)</option>
  <option value="de">German</option>
  <option value="dv">Divehi</option> 
  <option value="el">Greek</option>
  <option value="en-au">English (Australia)</option>
  <option value="en-ca">English (Canada)</option>
  <option value="en-gb">English (United Kingdom)</option>
  <option value="en-ie">English (Ireland)</option>
  <option value="en-il">English (Israel)</option>
  <option value="en-in">English (India)</option>
  <option value="en-nz">English (New Zealand)</option>  
  <option value="en-sg">English (Singapore)</option>  
  <option value="eo">Esperanto</option>
  <option value="es-do">Spanish (Dominican Republic)</option>
  <option value="es-mx">Spanish (Mexico)</option> 
  <option value="es-us">Spanish (United States)</option>
  <option value="es">Spanish</option>
  <option value="et">Estonian</option>
  <option value="eu">Basque</option>    
  <option value="fa">Persian</option>
  <option value="fi">Finnish</option>
  <option value="fil">Filipino</option>
  <option value="fo">Faroese</option>
  <option value="fr-ca">French (Canada)</option>
  <option value="fr-ch">French (Switzerland)</option>
  <option value="fr">French</option>
  <option value="fy">Western Frisian</option>
  <option value="gd">Scottish Gaelic</option>
  <option value="gl">Galician</option>
  <option value="gom-latn">gom (Latin)</option>
  <option value="gu">Gujarati</option> 
  <option value="he">Hebrew</option>
  <option value="hi">Hindi</option>
  <option value="hr">Croatian</option>
  <option value="hu">Hungarian</option>
  <option value="hy-am">Armenian (Armenia)</option> 
  <option value="id">Indonesian</option>
  <option value="is">Icelandic</option>
  <option value="it-ch">Italian (Switzerland)</option>
  <option value="it">Italian</option> 
  <option value="ja">Japanese</option>
  <option value="jv">Javanese</option> 
  <option value="ka">Georgian</option>
  <option value="kk">Kazakh</option>
  <option value="km">Khmer</option>
  <option value="kn">Kannada</option>
  <option value="ko">Korean</option>
  <option value="ku">Kurdish</option>
  <option value="ky">Kirghiz</option> 
  <option value="lb">Luxembourgish</option>
  <option value="lo">Lao</option>
  <option value="lt">Lithuanian</option>
  <option value="lv">Latvian</option>
  <option value="me">Montenegrin</option>
  <option value="mi">Maori</option>
  <option value="mk">Macedonian</option>
  <option value="ml">Malayalam</option>
  <option value="mn">Mongolian</option>
  <option value="mr">Marathi</option> 
  <option value="ms-my">Malay (Malaysia)</option>
  <option value="ms">Malay</option>
  <option value="mt">Maltese</option>
  <option value="my">Burmese</option>
  <option value="nb">Norwegian Bokmål</option>
  <option value="ne">Nepali</option> 
  <option value="nl-be">Dutch (Belgium)</option>
  <option value="nl">Dutch</option>
  <option value="nn">Norwegian Nynorsk</option> 
  <option value="pa-in">Punjabi (India)</option> 
  <option value="pl">Polish</option>
  <option value="pt-br">Portuguese (Brazil)</option> 
  <option value="pt">Portuguese</option> 
  <option value="ro">Romanian</option>
  <option value="ru">Russian</option>  
  <option value="sd">Sindhi</option>
  <option value="se">Northern Sami</option>
  <option value="si">Sinhala</option>
  <option value="sk">Slovak</option>
  <option value="sl">Slovenian</option>  
  <option value="sq">Albanian</option>
  <option value="sr-cyrl">Serbian (Cyrillic)</option>
  <option value="sr">Serbian</option>
  <option value="ss">Swati</option>
  <option value="sv">Swedish</option>
  <option value="sw">Swahili</option>  
  <option value="ta">Tamil</option>
  <option value="te">Telugu</option>
  <option value="tet">Tetum</option>
  <option value="tg">Tajik</option>
  <option value="th">Thai</option> 
  <option value="tk">Turkmen</option> 
  <option value="tl-ph">Tagalog (Philippines)</option>
  <option value="tlh">Klingon</option>
  <option value="tr">Turkish</option> 
  <option value="tzl">Talossan</option> 
  <option value="tzm-latn">Central Atlas Tamazight (Latin)</option>
  <option value="tzm">Central Atlas Tamazight</option>   
  <option value="ug-cn">Uyghur (China)</option> 
  <option value="uk">Ukrainian</option> 
  <option value="ur">Urdu</option>
  <option value="uz-latn">Uzbek (Latin)</option>
  <option value="uz">Uzbek</option>  
  <option value="vi">Vietnamese</option>  
  <option value="x-pseudo">Pseudo</option>  
  <option value="yo">Yoruba (Nigeria)</option>  
  <option value="zh-cn">Chinese (China)</option>
  <option value="zh-hk">Chinese (Hong Kong)</option>  
  <option value="zh-mo">Chinese (Macau)</option>
  <option value="zh-tw">Chinese (Taiwan)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @miken32 , I asked for if anything need to update I will update that. I am confused why you remove my that quote ?

Comment: It's quite common to edit out "chatter" from questions and answers. If you want to change your answer, feel free to at any time. But the answer body is not the place to solicit feedback from other users for those changes. (Note also the question was [correctly answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46130249/1255289) in 2017.)

Comment: @miken32 , your answer is different and my one is different. You have a good reputation here. So your work editing my answer beside any reason and give me negative reputation , is not a good deed. I hope next time you will encourage newbie rather hamper them.

Answer (score 1):

This function doesn't exist currently.  It was requested awhile back, and closed in favor of other related functionality.  I've reopened [the issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/843).

Answer (score 0):

`moment.locales()` returns array of locales like so:

[image]

To copy:

```
["en","af","ar-dz","ar-kw","ar-ly","ar-ma","ar-sa","ar-tn","ar","az","be","bg","bm","bn-bd","bn","bo","br","bs","ca","cs","cv","cy","da","de-at","de-ch","de","dv","el","en-au","en-ca","en-gb","en-ie","en-il","en-in","en-nz","en-sg","eo","es-do","es-mx","es-us","es","et","eu","fa","fi","fil","fo","fr-ca","fr-ch","fr","fy","ga","gd","gl","gom-deva","gom-latn","gu","he","hi","hr","hu","hy-am","id","is","it-ch","it","ja","jv","ka","kk","km","kn","ko","ku","ky","lb","lo","lt","lv","me","mi","mk","ml","mn","mr","ms-my","ms","mt","my","nb","ne","nl-be","nl","nn","oc-lnc","pa-in","pl","pt-br","pt","ro","ru","sd","se","si","sk","sl","sq","sr-cyrl","sr","ss","sv","sw","ta","te","tet","tg","th","tk","tl-ph","tlh","tr","tzl","tzm-latn","tzm","ug-cn","uk","ur","uz-latn","uz","vi","x-pseudo","yo","zh-cn","zh-hk","zh-mo","zh-tw"]
```

though `moment.locale()` returns current active locale, like so:

[image]