# Does the chartjs supports localization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Does the chartjs support localization?

If yes, what is the best way to implement localization on the client side charts?

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js uses [moment](https://momentjs.com/) for date-handling. You can set the locale globally on moment before initializing the chart.

1. Import `moment-with-locales.min.js` in your HTML.
2. Set the [locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109303/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-available-locale-keys-from-momentjs-with-locale) in a JavaScript: `moment.locale('sv-SE');`
3. Inititialize your chart.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about localizing dates, you need to first make sure the chart displays dates that can be parsed by the JavaScript's `toLocaleDateString` function.
e.g. `options.scales.xAxes[0].time.displayFormats.day = 'h:mm:ss a';`
The list of possible formats is https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/time.html

Then, again, in your `options` json `options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks`, set a callback to your date value where you can localize it like shown below.

```
callback: function (value) {
  return new Date(value).toLocaleDateString('ja-JP', {
    dateStyle: 'long',
    timeStyle: 'long'
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, chartjs has nothing to do with localization; and no, it doesn't.

They even have [no support](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/615) for flipping labels etc. But you shouldn't have any problems unless you need to display rtl charts.

Comment: thanks. What is the best way to implement localization using JS?

Comment: There's no "best way". You have too many options. Just do a quick research and find what suites your project the best. A quick google search gives 51 million results 