# react big calendar start week from monday instead of sunday?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

use react-big-calendar.js and moment.js

setLocalizer code

```
moment.locale('ko');
BigCalendar.setLocalizer(
  BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment)
);
```

first day of the week is always Sunday

I want to see it from Monday.

The associated url.

https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar/issues/28

But there is no example.

what should I do?

---

find answer

```
moment.locale('ko',{
  week:{
    dow : 1
  }
});
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I also wanted to change `react-big-calendar` first day of week to Monday.
Thank you for your question, because it helped me to find a way of changing it.
Try the following code snippet is from my project:

```
moment.locale('ko', {
    week: {
        dow: 1,
        doy: 1,
    },
});

BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment);
```

So the full extract looks something like:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';

moment.locale('ko', {
    week: {
        dow: 1,
        doy: 1,
    },
});
BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment);

const Main = (props) => <BigCalendar
    events={props.events}
    startAccessor={'start'}
    endAccessor={'end'}
    titleAccessor={'title'}
    allDayAccessor={'allDay'}
    onNavigate={props.onNavigate}
/>;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Roman. This works for me. What is `ko`, `dow` and `doy` means in `moment.locale`?

Comment: @HemanthaDhanushka.

In this context 'ko' represents the required locale name (Korean in this case). [List of available locales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55827203/8013693). 'dow' represents, that the week will start with Monday. 'doy' works together with 'dow' to determine first week of the year. More informtion about 'doy' can be found [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/dow-doy/).