# moment locale is not setting the locale locally

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization, momentjs

I have dates in various culture (e.g. 19.10.2020 (German) 2020/10/19 (english)) So now while saving the data to datatbase I have to revert all the format to basic en-US culture (YYYY-MM-DD) . For this I did following-

```
//// this method will convert the date of any locales (e.g. fr, de, ja, sv, nb) to en-US locale to save the date in DB
  reverseDateToEnLocale(date: string, format?: string) {
    var locale = moment();
    locale.locale(this.locale); //// this.locale is the set locale fr, zh, de, en etc.
    if (!format) { format = "YYYY-MM-DD"; } //// the format I want to convert for saving in database
    var localeFormat = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L'); ///// to get the set moment locale date format
    return moment(date, localeFormat).format(format); /// convert the format to expected en
  }
```

but when I set in

```
    var locale = moment();
    locale.locale(this.locale); 
    console.log(moment().locale()); // everytime reverts me the en
```

I don't want to change the global moment locale set. I just want it to use only within the function to revert and to get the desired result that is english date format for any locale date format.

This piece of code works fine when it is german format but doesn't work for chinese format. I am not understanding that what is missed.

```
when I pass 'zh' as locale then locale in moment is not getting set. And returning me the wrong format
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/ I have tried setting using below as well

```
moment.locale('en'); // default the locale to English
var localLocale = moment();

localLocale.locale('fr'); // set this instance to use French
localLocale.format('LLLL'); // dimanche 15 juillet 2012 11:01
moment().format('LLLL'); // Sunday, July 15 2012 11:01 AM
```

But it isn't working
Please could you tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got to know that there are list of moments locales which are applicable and understood by moment. And the localeId I was passing was 'zh-Hant' which is not accepted by moment. Moment has its own list of locales. Please check here -

[How to obtain a list of available locale keys from momentjs with locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109303/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-available-locale-keys-from-momentjs-with-locale)

Hence, It took me long time to figure that out. If we are using moment for dates and number format, Then use the locales ONLY AND ONLY accepted by them. Otherwise It may create an issue if we pass different locales and it will break.